# How to get text element in html head by selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, firefox

I am trying to get a file name of a jpg from this [link](https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/a/AVvXsEhqKZPYd_qHCD796j235oF96RgM_uCvhE6BmqbiknM2j--5fmG4KdeKvnHT2AWxhpuNGaFtIJorg1ArkUyTeTwMXPuqqmnnw4KSlmYaOs_Hl1xIM4_zFA3GTJ9HdrkFdG_4wSwPOkOjfsrEnWoCmVGxdPOl12tXqEMVZJvwEqbJFCnaTryELA9CsvCG=w1800?jpg) by selenium (Firefox driver). If I manually right click on the photo and download it, the file name will be **1-002.jpg**

When I try to browse the html by Firefox, it shows that **1-002.jpg** is located in the <'head'> <'title'>section. This can't be shown on chrome for some reason.

```
<Head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height;">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="resource://content-accessible/ImageDocument.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="resource://content-accessible/TopLevelImageDocument.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome://global/skin/media/TopLevelImageDocument.css">
 <title>1-002.jpg (JPEG Image, 1800&nbsp;×&nbsp;2546 pixels) — Scaled (40%)</title>
</Head>
```

However, I am unable to get the text. So far my codes are below

```
driver.get(url)

file_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/head/title')
print(file_name)
```

I can only get `<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="384e7def-df66-4f06-9c3a-c5072c2d650f", element="7e0002d0-7bfb-4aed-8558-fdb9c25075d4")>`

if I replace it by  `file_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/head/title').text` , it will return nothing.

So I am asking how can I get the wanted text.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will have to check in HTMLDOM that we have unique entry or not :

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

For firefox please do inspect and steps should remain same.

If `/html/head/title` is 1/1, then the issue could be cause of delay.

**Hardcoded sleep (Not recommended)**

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
file_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/head/title').text
print(file_name)
```

**Code trial 2 :** (Recommended)

```
file_name =  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/head/title"))).text
print(file_name)
```

Other things you can try out :

Please call `.get_attribute('innerText')` or `.get_attribute('innerHTML')`
instead of `.text`, like this :

With **innerHTML**

```
file_name =  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/head/title"))).get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(file_name)
```

**With innerText**

```
file_name =  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/head/title"))).text
print(file_name)get_attribute('innerText')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation. The problem is not related to delay issue. I solved the problem with 
    file_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/head/title').get_attribute('innerText')

Answer (score 0):

`driver.get_title()`

I was trying to get the `<head><title>` for a different reason, and this was much simpler than XPath.