# Get element value from dynamic website using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm trying to get the value of the vending price of AMZN index market directly from the trading platform plus500, the value changes continuosly so I have to use selenium. The code I'm using is this one:

```
driver.get("https://app.plus500.com/trade/amazon")
# get AMZN vending price
Sell = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, value="sell")
print(Sell)
```

The html from the source is this:

```
<div class="sell" data-no-trading="false" id="_win_plus500_bind873" data-show="true">126.28</div>
```

I need to scrape the value (in this case 126,28) every time it changes.
If it is needed I created a dummy Plus500 account for you: username "myrandomcode@gmail.com" password: "MyRandomCode87".

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69798372/how-to-get-text-element-in-html-head-by-selenium

Answer (score 0):

To extract the value of the vending price of AMZN index market directly from the trading platform [**plus500**](https://app.plus500.com/trade/amazon) i.e. the text ***126.28*** as the element is a dynamic element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@class, 'section-table-body')]//span[text()='Amazon']//following::div[2]"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

Comment: if I have to do it with other data where can I find this code "//div[starts-with(@class, 'section-table-body')]//span[text()='Amazon']//following::div[2]" I tryed to copy the xpath and full xpath but they are not the same as the code you wrote